# GetResponse not coming back using HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Using form contenttype, I am getting stuck at this line:

```
var webresponse = (HttpWebResponse)webrequest.GetResponse();
```

For the url, you can use any value.  Here is the full code:

```
public bool test() 
{

    string url = "https://www.google.com";

    // Create a new HTTP request object, set the method to POST and write the POST data to it
    var webrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.CreateHttp(url);
    webrequest.Method = "POST";
    webrequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    using (Stream postStream = webrequest.GetRequestStream())
    {
        //
    }

    // Make the request, get a response and pull the data out of the response stream
    var webresponse = (HttpWebResponse)webrequest.GetResponse();
    Stream responseStream = webresponse.GetResponseStream();
    var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);

    string result = reader.ReadToEnd();

    // Normal Completion
    return true;
}
```

Does anyone know why it would get stuck on this line and not come back (when you are doing debugging):

```
var webresponse = (HttpWebResponse)webrequest.GetResponse();
```

Thank You

Comment: have you tried closing the stream first?

Comment: According to the .net docs, you don't need to call close until you are done with it:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue. My guess is that the environment where this code is running cannot reach the endpoint. To check for this, log onto the server as the application domain service account, open a browser, and see if you can hit the endpoint manually.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem! I was calling the method as an async task:

```
private async Task starttest()
{
    clsTester objTester = new clsTester();
    objTester.test();
}
```

...

```
var result = Task.Run(async () => await starttest());
```

I removed all that code and changed it to a worker thread:

```
private Thread workerThread = null;
private void starttest()
{
    clsTester objTester = new clsTester();
    objTester.test();
}
```

And then called it as follows:

...

```
// Initialise and start worker thread
this.workerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.starttest));
this.workerThread.Start();
```

Everything is working now.